# How can I bind event to outside of element?

Tags: jquery, events

Let's say we have box. In this box is another box (box2). I want to activate an event when mouse is clicked in box, but I do not want to activate it if it's clicked on box2. How can I achieve this? I just want to bind the event to box but exclude box2. I made a test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<style>
.box {width: 300px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;}
.box2 {width: 10px;height:8px;border:1px solid red;z-index:2;}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.box').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"><div class="box2"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this test case I want to alert when mouse is clicked outside of box2. Unfortunately, it activates no matter what is under cursor, all it cares is if it's in box. So, how can I activate it if it's clicked in box, but not activate it if it's clicked on box2 (red box)?

Comment: "I just want to bind event to box"... Events bubble up the DOM, so you're going to have to bind an event to box2 as well. Just use the `stopPropagation` method of the event object inside that event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
$('.box2').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make 2 clickhandlers, one for 'box' and one for 'box2'.
With the handler for box2, you set a variable 'box2', set true if you clicked on 'box2'.
Check for this variable in the clickhandler for 'box' and it works!

Use this as javascript

```
$(function() {
    var box2 = false;
    $('.box2').click(function() {
        box2 = true;
    });
    $('.box').click(function() {
        if(!box2){
            alert('clicked');
        }
    });
});
```